# Does Apple approve the usage of setKeepAliveTimeout:handler methode for updating GPS location to server?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I'm writing an application that needs once in a while to update the server about the user's location while the application is running in the background. I know I can do this by using the  setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: method. I know that this method is specially for VoIP application but I was wondering if Apple will allow this usage for location update to server?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:) says that your handler only get 10 seconds to keep the network connection alive for voip calls when using `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:` method.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777499/setkeepalivetimeout-and-backgroundtasks/4777549#4777549).

This call is for **voip** apps and you must have `voip` in your `UIBackgroundModes` key (info.plist).  Using this would probably get rejected unless you are writing a voip app.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this `setKeepAliveTimeout`.

I recommend to read this Apple's officatin documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

One of the things, which iOS provide is a callback on a location change. Your application will be awoken for short period of time and you will receive this callback and should be able to send your location to the server.

BTW. You will need `location` backgrounding mode for this.

And progmr is right. You will need voip backgrounding mode to use setKeepAliveTimeout. And if your application isn't a real voip application, almost guaranteed that your app will be rejected.