# periodically download file from server and notify the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Again I have a similar doubt as specified in the link [setKeepAliveTimeout and BackgroundTasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777499/setkeepalivetimeout-and-backgroundtasks).

I have to periodically take a file from server and accordingly provide local notification.
This has to be done when app is in background state.

Comment: The only way to do something like this via a supported API is with push notifications.  Regular apps can't do any downloads in the background for more than a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Create backgoud task in your interface:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
```

Than create method to backgroud working:

```
- (void) backgroundMethod {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //create backgriund task;
    self.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.bgTask];
        self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    //do your stuff;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.bgTask];
    self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
}
```

And call it whenewer you want periodicaly.

Comment: thanks.. I tried the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220494/how-do-i-make-my-app-run-an-nstimer-in-the-background .. which was exactly what I need.. Thanks ..